# convert binary file to hexadecimal characters

Tags: c

How do I convert the contents of a binary file into hexadecimal?

ex. test.bin contains

```
abcdefghijklmn in binary
```

Convert contents to output.txt which will contain

```
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e
```

Answer (score 4):

To print a value in hexadecimal format you can use `"%x"` [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Here is a little program that prints the the contents in hex of files given as command line arguments. To print to an output file, use [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        FILE* fp = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
        if (fp) { /* ignore if failed to open */
            int c;
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
                printf(" %02x", c);
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Application which converts string from file to hexadecimal numbers and saves it to another file:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char tonum(char c)
{
  return c + (c < 10 ? 48 : 87);
}

void to_hex(int input, char* output)
{
  int p = input / 16;
  output[0] = tonum(p);
  output[1] = tonum(input - p*16);

}

int main(void)
{
  FILE *input = fopen("input", "r");
  FILE *output = fopen("output", "w");
  int x;
  char out[4] = {0}; out[2] = ' ';
  while  ((x = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    {
      to_hex(x, out);
      fputs(out, output);
    }
  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The magic constants `48` and `87` are obscure and non portable.  Use `'0'` and `'a' - 10` instead.

Comment: You should use binary mode for the input file: `fopen("input", "rb");`

Answer (score 0):

This program will do (i think) what you want:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FALSE   0
#define TRUE    (!FALSE)

#define TAM_BUFFER  16

char *nomprog;  /* nombre del programa */

void error (int, char *, ...);
void signal_handler (int);

main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    /* valor booleano para ver si se procesa stdin */
    int procesar_stdin;
    int res;

    /* Instalamos el tratamiento de interrupciones */
    signal (SIGHUP, signal_handler);
    signal (SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal (SIGTERM, signal_handler);

    procesar_stdin = TRUE;
    res = 0;
    for (nomprog = *argv, argc--, argv++; argc > 0; argc--, argv++) {
        procesar_stdin = FALSE;
        fp = fopen (*argv, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            error (0, "Error al abrir \"%s\"", *argv);
            res = 1;
            continue;
        }
        printf("[%s]:\n", *argv);
        procesa (fp);
    }
    if (procesar_stdin) procesa (stdin);
    exit (res);
} /* main */


volatile int interrumpido = FALSE;
void signal_handler (int dumb)
{
    interrumpido = TRUE;
}

procesa (FILE *fp)
{
    unsigned char   buffer [TAM_BUFFER];
    unsigned char   bufferref [TAM_BUFFER];
    unsigned long   offset;
    int     leidos,
            asterisco;

    for (   offset = 0L;
        (!interrumpido) &&
        ((leidos = fread (buffer,
            sizeof (unsigned char),
            TAM_BUFFER,
            fp)) > 0);
        offset += leidos)
    {
        int j;

        if (    offset != 0 &&
            memcmp (buffer, bufferref, TAM_BUFFER) == 0)
        {
            if (!asterisco) printf ("*\n");
            asterisco = 1;
            continue;
        }
        asterisco = 0;
        memcpy (bufferref, buffer, TAM_BUFFER);
        printf ("%08lx : ", offset);
        for (j = 0; j < TAM_BUFFER; j++)
            if (j < leidos)
                printf ("%02x ", buffer [j]);
            else    printf ("   ");
        printf (": ");
        for (j = 0; j < TAM_BUFFER; j++)
            if (j < leidos)
                if (isprint (buffer [j]))
                    printf ("%c", buffer [j]);
                else    printf (".");
            else    break;
        printf ("\n");
    } /* for */
    printf ("%08x\n", offset);
} /* procesa */


void error (int n, char *cad, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    char mensaje [1000];

    va_start (p, cad);
    vsprintf (mensaje, cad, p);
    va_end (p);
    if (n) {
        fprintf (stderr,
            "\n%s: \007ERROR: %s\n",
            nomprog,
            mensaje);
        exit (n);
    } else  fprintf (stderr,
            "\n%s: \007WARNING: %s\n",
            nomprog,
            mensaje);
} /* error */
```

Sorry, but it's commented in spanish :}  It's an old program i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally, use octal dump command to convert the string.  See here:

```
$ echo abcdefg | od -t x1 -An
 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 0a
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted as **not useful**. Explain what it does and how it's different / better than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29750309)